# image binding in angular 5 equivalent to BitmapImage binding in silverlight c#

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I'm trying to move my project from silverlight to Angular5. I need to show image on the UI. I'm using the same service(in c#) which i used for silverlight and it returns a byte[] along with a bunch of data as a class object. How to convert it into a Bitmap Image or anything and how to bind this to the `<img class="immg-up img-ht-sp-2" src="data:image/png;base64," onerror="this.src='./images/image df.png'" />` in html. I'm using typescript and also need to know the equivalent type of byte[] in c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to to use a data URI for the image, then you need to either return Base64 text from your C# service, or convert it to Base64 in the Angular code.

Assuming this is done and stored in a property called `imageData`, this should do it:

```
<img class="immg-up img-ht-sp-2" src="data:image/png;base64,{{imageData}}" onerror="this.src='./images/image df.png'" />
```

Comment: `public imageData: string;` and can you say the type instead of string in typescript

Comment: Yes, that's right. I left that out because where comes from doesn't matter so much as how the binding is done.